# django. User adding items in model dropdown box

Tags: python, django, django-models

In models.py i have set choices. What would the best way to go about enabling the user to add more choices into the dropdown box.

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
     BUILDING_MATERIALS = (
        ('Brick', 'Brick'),
        ('Stone', 'Stone'),
        ('Breeze Block', 'Breeze Block'),
        ('Wooden', 'Wooden'),
        ('Pre Fap', 'Pre Fap'),
    )
    materials = models.CharField(max_length=12, choices=BUILDING_MATERIALS, null=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then, this is a sign to have a separate model for building blocks:

```
class Material(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=12, null=False)
```

You `Location` model would be related to the `Material` model. In case `location` can only have a single `material`, it would be a [`ForeignKey`:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

```
class Location(models.Model):
    materials = models.ForeignKey(Material)
```